# IA-32 x86 data alignment

Tags: x86

Everything i can find just told me that i should align because it can be more efficient, but i can't find what's the hw issue why i should do that on IA-32. It is because the address bus needs address divisible by 4 for instance? Or because the RAM can give only aligned data without performance loss? Or?

http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs164/sp05/ia32-refs/ia32-chapter-two.pdf

> On the ia32, there is no requirement for data alignment. A program
>   will work correctly with four-byte integers regardless of where they
>   are located. For example, a four byte integer could be located at
>   addresses 1,2,3,4. **However, the machine executes much more efficiently
>   if, for example, four byte integers are on a four byte boundary, so a
>   better choice of starting address for a four byte integer is an
>   address that is a multiple of 4.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a hardware-related problem. Usually RAM modules are connected as follows:

[image]

If an aligned access occurs, modules 1, 2, 3 and 4 are selected at the same time and thus the 32 bits can be read in one memory read cycle.

If an unaligned access occurs, let's say for example 2 bytes off, then modules 1, 2, 3 and 4 are selected at first read cycle, where only the higher 2 bytes (lower 2 bytes of the data we are fetching) are read (modules 3 and 4); on next read cycle modules 5, 6, 7 and 8 are selected, where only the lower 2 bytes (higher 2 bytes of the data we are fetching) are read.

A more detailed view of the RAM modules (simplified for a 4-bit machine with capacity for 4 words).

[image: 4-bit RAM]

In this diagram it's pretty clear that you can only select one row of flip-flops because the decoder will only activate one of its output lines, the 3 others will remain at 0.

Note that some architectures force you to align all memory accesses by throwing a bus error if accessing an unaligned address (i.e. MIPS), while others will do as many read cycles as required to fetch the needed data (i.e. x86), although of course this requires additional hardware (usually an [MMU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit)).

Comment: Then, when it comes to reading 8-bytes variable with 64-bits CPU, is it enough to align the variable into 4-bytes if the RAM is aligned 4-bytes like your example?

Comment: As explained, this is highly hardware-dependant. For example, if the alignment word is truly 64-bits, then you need to align on 8-bytes. If the alignment is actually 32-bits, you need to align on 4-bytes.